# What is the item required when interrogating the Regent's Envoy?

Tags: lost-ark

There's a selection with 100 Required, but I am not sure what that icon represents under "You cannot ignore Scherrit's tyranny":

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the Wisdom icon:

[image]

100 Wisdom is required to select that option. There will be other virtue blocked responses in the game noted by their corresponding icon and level requirement.

Comment: You can select it, but it will just produce a generic response.